# Is there some structured format for drawing source control branching diagrams?

Tags: version-control, graph, diagrams

Everyone on my team draws branch diagrams differently, including how branches exit or reintegrate to the parent, how cherry-pick merges are shown, and a host of other aesthetic choices.

Is there some structured format for drawing source control branches (like UML but for source control)?

Comment: The [Git manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) has some diagrams. It seems to be a decent format and certainly familiar to anyone who uses Git and reads that manual. I am not sure if there is a way to generate similar diagrams consistently though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want standardization I sugest a [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) with .dot format. It's well known lib for drawing networks and flowcharts. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: It's a neat tool, but I haven't found a way to have it actually draw branches in terms of trunk/branches. For instance, when you tell it to graph from a "branch" back to trunk (merge), it just draws a line back to the node. That's no way to visualize branching :/

Comment: hehe :D try this: [git-big-picture](https://github.com/esc/git-big-picture), [js-graphviz-lib-gitShower](http://gitgraphjs.com/), [neto command line from git to graphviz](http://chiu01.blogspot.com/2012/04/git-tip-using-graphviz-to-display.html) and [another git graphs](http://correl.phoenixinquis.net/2015/07/12/git-graphs.html). This links all use graphviz for visualization...

Comment: @Sinaesthetic : Did some of this links hellps?

Comment: Yes it helped, thank you. i didn't find any *product* , but with all the options, js-graphviz turned out enough for now. I also found http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/ which has some features that can be used in the the same way.